# In-app iOS "Confirm your in app purchases" will pop out purchase list view

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a purchase list:

```
item 1 $0.99 Buy
item 2 $1.99 Buy
item 3 $2.99 Buy
```

When I click Buy button will get "Confirm your In-App purchases" warning window. No matter I select "Buy" or "Cancel" this warning window will disappear (this is right), but the purchase list view controller is pop out to its parent view controller. I don't know why.

I tried many ways, get the same result --  the list view controller will pop out when I click "Confirm your In-App purchases" warning window "Cancel" or "Buy" button. just tell why.

This is the code in list view click pay button:

```
- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *searchString ;
    if (buyButton.tag == 0) {
        searchString = PURCHASES_REMOVE_AD;
    }else if (buyButton.tag == 1){
        searchString = PURCHASES_COFFEE;
    }else if (buyButton.tag == 2){
        searchString = PURCHASES_MONEY;
    }
    for (SKProduct *product in _products) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:searchString]) {
            [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I come to this page:

[image]

as you see in this picture, when I click "Cancel" or "Buy" button, the "Buy" view controller will disappear back to parent view controller,

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

this is the code I click cancel button, don't see any problem.

### Update

I finally figured it out. I create list view's parent view controller in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application. Now I move the creation to - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions the problem's gone. Any one can tell me why?

Comment: Why vote me down, at lease give me a reason, please!!!

Comment: Add a breakpoint when your view will move to a different parent. Try to find out what is triggering the view change. Have you added some code that's doing it (I assume the answer is yes).

Comment: Ok, make something the delegate of the navigation controller or subclass it and add a breakpoint when the view controller is popped. You need to find the trigger.

Comment: I set break point at list view -(void)viewWillDisappear find after cancel button clicked - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application in AppDelegate.m is called...

Comment: I finally figured it out. I create list view's parent view controller in  `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`. Now I move the creation to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` the problem's gone. Any one can tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Your application actually looses focus when a modal from StoreKit is displayed. As a result, when the user tapped either button in the SK dialog, [your application became active again](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a), and since you created the controller in response to the application becoming active, it created a new instance of it, effectively hiding what was previously on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you was not set 'delegate' of SKProductsRequest.

```
SKProductsRequest *request;
request.delegate = self; // self or target. did you?
```

and I attach reference [In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough - troybrant.net](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

edit -- 2013/10/15

When did click 'Purchase Popup' after then called - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive: method. so... Purchase ViewController will be regenerated. so SKProductsRequest's delegate can not found maybe.

[iOS Application life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do set the request, see my update

Answer (score 0):

applicationDidBecomeActive is called multiple times after an application's launch. For example, when the Location Services popup comes up when an app starts, after the user clicks "OK", the applicationDidBecomeActive method is called again.

My guess is that this same behavior occurs when the "Confirm Your In App Purchase" dialog pops up. Since you were **recreating** the parent's view controller in the applicationDidBecomeActive method, my guess is just as you pressed the OK or BUY button, the parent view was being reinitialized completely which caused the unexpected behavior.

You can stick an NSLog in your applicationDidBecomeActive method to confirm this.